# Do we have evidence of heritable personality traits in chimpanzees?

Tags: genetics

I have read that chimpanizees have distinct personalities. Do we have evidence of heritable personality traits in them?

Comment: you should add some details such as what all do you include in personality traits. I am not sure if personalities are heritable in humans. Personality has a very large environmental component

Comment: Can you add some more background? Where did you read this?

Comment: @WYSIWYG the Big Five are considered to have up to 50% heritability in humans, so I don't see a problem with the premise. I don't know if there is sufficient research on personality traits in apes (or how researchers would deal with the distortion which being lab-reared will introduce to a twin study), but I find the question quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

There has been some research in order to explore this direction, for instance, see this reference:

[A. Weiss et al. - "*The Heritability of Personality Factors in Chimpanzees*", Behavior Genetics, Vol. 30, No. 3, 2000.](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Aurelio_Figueredo/publication/12223447_The_heritability_of_personality_factors_in_chimpanzees_(Pan_troglodytes)/links/00b7d5319d00f58589000000.pdf),

in which the authors study five human-like factors - Surgency,
Dependability, Emotional Stability, Agreeableness, and Openness.

Quoting verbatim their findings:

> Only Dominance ... was significantly heritable. Dependability showed evidence that it might be heritable, but the parameter estimates were not statistically significant ... Two other personality traits, Agreeableness and Emotional Stability, showed positive heritability estimates but the parameter
>   estimates were nonsignificant and small. Openness and Surgency showed no evidence of heritability.

In fact, the statistical correlation between dominance and heritability makes a strong sense.  Here's what I make out of this - this was a correlation based study, or kind of an experiment, hence the stress on statistical significance. But the question it raises is - is there a causal relationship between the two, i.e. does there exist any proper *mechanism* for the inheritance of "dominance". Finding such a mechanism was clearly beyond the scope of this study, but I believe the requisite answer for your question is if one stumbles on to such mechanisms, and not statistical correlations, which are mere pointers.

But on the basis of the study at least, all that one can safely conclude is - *statistical correlations suggest that inheritance of "dominance" appears plausible, but the exact mechanism of how this implements out in practice, is beyond the scope of this study*.